# R: Brace expansion in Sys.glob()

Tags: r, filesystems, glob

Is it possible to have R's Sys.glob() function expand braces?  What I mean is a pattern similar to /home/foo/{a,b}/bar.txt should find files /home/foo/a/bar.txt and /home/foo/b/bar.txt should they both exist. By default R does not expand the braces.

Brace expansion is possible in glob(3) with the GLOB_BRACE flag. I am guessing R is just calling glob(3) underneath the covers so I hope there is some way, but I can't seem to find the right invocation...

Answer (score 2):

The `bracer` package's `glob()` function is a wrapper around `Sys.glob()` that finds files after performing brace expansion.  In your particular example `bracer::glob("/home/foo/{a,b}/bar.txt")` would indeed find files `/home/foo/a/bar.txt` and `/home/foo/b/bar.txt` if they should both exist.

Answer (score 1):

I just mention, that you could also use `system` (with the intern param set to TRUE) and call whatever system command you want to use if it isn't exposed directly in `Sys.*()` in R.  For example, this just calls `ls` for csv files:

```
x <- system("ls *.csv", intern=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds useful.

The actual work is done by the `do_glob()` subroutine in the file `src/main/sysutils.c` in the R sources -- maybe you can start there with work towards a patch?

`GLOB_MARK` is already added conditionally (on being available) so maybe you can shadow that work?

Comment: I will look into it. The actual coding part is easy; it's the getting involved in such a large and mature project is where all the effort lies...